# Generic method type and method parameter does not match

Tags: c#, generics, types, parameters, constraints

I just stumbled over that and I can't really explain that. Say I have that code:

```
public interface IFeature  {  }

public class FeatureA : IFeature { }

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var feature = new FeatureA();
    Load(feature);
  }

  private static void Load(IFeature featureDefinition)
  {
    Activate(featureDefinition);
  }

  private static void Activate<TFeature>(TFeature featureDefinition) where TFeature : IFeature
  {
    var featureType = typeof(TFeature);
    var sameType = featureType == featureDefinition.GetType();
    // sameType == false
  }
}
```

Now `featureType` is always of type `IFeature` and not of the type of the parameter `featureDefinition`. Can someone explain why?

I expected

```
featureType == featureDefinition.GetType()
```

to be true...

**edit:**

So above is a complete working example of the code.

Now it's quite clear to me: The parameter is non generic, thus always of type `IFeature`. I guess there is a reason for a small working example :-P

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Does not look valid at all. Please provide [MCVE] - code you've shown does work perfectly fine (assuming you actually pass instances of classes that implement the interface and not variables of type `IFeature`).

Comment: I don't believe that code you've just added will actually behave as you described :) You really should come up with proper sample as it does not look like you will be able to delete the question...

Comment: Okay that's weired. I did a small example with the code and you are right. The problem must be somewhere else. I will update the question as soon as I know :-(

Comment: Check out samples I've added to the answer (may need to look at history) - probably you losing type somewhere - so you'll be able to narrow down question or just reword the post to "I think it should work (as clearly shown by sample ...) but sometimes does not"

Comment: I've updated the question :-) So it seems I'm "losing" the type information by the `IFeature` paremeter in the calling method, right? Because it's non generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thereason is that `TFeature` will be the type with that the Activate function has been called. This can be `IFeature` or any class or interface implementing it. For example, it is perfectly valid to call Activate like that:

```
Activate<IFeature>(feature);
```

In that case, the compiler creates the generic method Activate using the type `IFeature` as type parameter and the result is a method that is perfectly valid to call. However, if you call it like

```
Activate<Feature>(feature);
```

where `Feature` implements `IFeature`, then the compiler will of course use `Feature` as generic type parameter and again the method is valid to call.

You might have difficulties what happens when you just call the method like

```
Activate(feature);
```

In that case, the compiler uses the type that he thinks fits best, based on static analysis as compilers always do. It is **not using the runtime type** of the object since this is obviously not known to the compiler. Rather, the compiler tries to infer the least common type that can be used as a type parameter.

In this case, the compiler will check what interfaces are implemented by the static type of `feature` and if it matches the conditions, the static type of `feature` is used as generic type parameter. Otherwise, the compiler will throw an error message that the generic type is unclear.

For example, you can always make the compiler forget about the static type by explicitly overriding it:

```
object objFeature = feature;
Activate(objFeature);
```

Now, this code will raise a compiler error since the static type of `objFeature` is `Object` and this does not fulfill the constraint that it should be implementing `IFeature`. This is independent on the true type of `feature` which you only get at runtime through `feature.GetType()`.

Inferrence samples:

```
// typeof(TFeature) inside Activate returning `IFeature`:
IFeature f = new FeatureImpl(); 
Activate(f); // compiled into Activate<IFeature>(...) 

// FeatureImpl:FeatureBase:IFeature
// typeof(TFeature) inside Activate returning `FeatureImpl`:
var f1 = new FeatureImpl(); 
Activate(f1); // compiled into Activate<FeatureImpl>(...) 

FeatureBase f2 = new FeatureImpl(); 
Activate(f2); // compiled into Activate<FeatureBase>(...)
```

Comment: Likely correct answer to the puzzle question. Consider showing complete sample for type inference in addition to explicitly specifying the type.

Comment: You are correct: I'm calling it without the generic parameter. I thought the parameter will be determined on runtime...

Comment: Georg - I've added inferrence samples to your post - feel free to revert/edit (sorry can't have "suggested edits")

Comment: @derape No. The type parameters are inferred at compile-time. If you want to call the method with the generic type parameter determined at runtime, this is also possible through reflection but it is much more complex.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks :)